# Unable to publish artifact into GitHub packages using GitHub actions

Tags: java, maven, github-actions, cicd, github-package-registry

I am new to GitHub Actions, I am trying to publish maven-based artifacts to the GitHub package using Github Actions.

This is is the error I am getting.

### **
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy)  Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact  from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/******************): transfer failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/*****************-0.0.1.jar, status: 422 Unprocessable Entity -> [Help 1]
**

Below is the YAML file I used to publish this artifact to GitHub packages.

```
name: Maven Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        server-id: github # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
        settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }} # location for the settings.xml file

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

    - name: Publish to GitHub Packages Apache Maven
      run: mvn deploy -s $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/settings.xml
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
```

Comment: What is the size of the artifacts?